# Casting an int to specific Enum at runtime from derived class

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I have a group of classes that all are derived from the same base class, and all define unique Enums of the same name.

```cs
public class DerivedClassOne : BaseClass
{
    public enum Flags
    {
        None = 0,
        cheese = 1,
        ham = 2,
        egg = 4
    }
}

public class DerivedClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    public enum Flags
    {
        None = 0,
        bacon = 1,
        lettuce = 2,
        tomato = 4
    }
}
```

How would I, with only an instance of `BaseClass`, be able to cast an int (n) to this enum and store it at runtime? ie:

```cs
object flag = (BaseClassInstance.Enums.Flags)n;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Dai The `flag` value is passed to an interface method of the derived classes as a parameter, where the retained type is important.

Comment: @leahshmovie That sounds like a poorly designed interface then, as it won't be strongly-typed.

Comment: @Dai I'll take a look at redesigning the interface. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) enums as `Enum` (which is somewhat better than `Object`), then you can do this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract Enum ConvertInt32ToSomeEnumType( Int32 value );
}

public class DerivedClassOne : BaseClass
{
    public override Enum ConvertInt32ToSomeEnumType( Int32 value ) => (DerivedClassOne.Flags)value;
}

public class DerivedClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    public override Enum ConvertInt32ToSomeEnumType( Int32 value ) => (DerivedClassTwo.Flags)value;
}
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]